# Redux router infinite loop from componentWillMount

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have the following code

```
componentWillMount(){
    this.props.getCourse(null, this.props.location.query.course_id);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    var currCourse_id = this.props.course_details.course_id;
    var nextCourse_id = this.props.location.query.course_id;
    if (nextCourse_id !== currCourse_id) {
      this.props.getCourse(null, nextCourse_id);
    }
  }
```

I tried all sorts of combinations in the CWRP function but I end up with an infinite loop. The screen changes to the new course, though. Any suggestions on what to add in `currCourse_id` and `nextCourse_id` will be helpful. I'm trying to dispatch the `getCourse` action (which is an API endpoint) and update the component with the new props.

Comment: There is no use of nextProps. is that intentional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing this line -

```
var nextCourse_id = nextProps.location.query.course_id;
```

Comment: I had to also change the `currCourse_id` to `this.props.location.query.course_id`